# How to quickly draw something and send as image directly from the keyboard?

Tags: keyboard, images

The usual keyboard lets handwrite something, but it digitizes the handwrite before sending it. On the other hand, many apps allow direct sending of an image or gif.

How can I quickly prevent digitizing and send the handwritten text or drawn image like an image file?

Comment: Also on SoftwareRecs.SE: https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/87452/520

Comment: Could you clarify  what is it your looking for .  When you say digitize what do u mean ? - convert to text ? . No keyboard apps do not do what google lens does.  If you mean to send an image or handwritten notes  all u do is capture a sreenshot of that  image. Gboard will store that image in its clipboard ( enable clipboard )

Comment: @user1874594 I believe OP wants the latter, similar to [the handwriting feature on the (now defunct) MSN Messenger](http://johnbokma.com/messenger/handwriting-msn-beta.html)

Comment: @user1874594 as per andrew comment.

Answer (score 1):

These are  ways you can get done what I think you want done. Its possible  to share your handwrtitten screenshot as an image. But that is *limited by the app  your sharing it with rather than gboard ( e.g. some messenger or whatsapp )and its permissiveness to allow pasting images besides text*. Other alternatives to gboard   IMHO do not allow  handwriting input e.g. swiftkey though they  may offer a `clipboard` feature

-- Turn `Gboard` into a handwriting pad area. Under `settings`- thee is a `handwriting option per language` if its available. Most languages  have it available.  When you use the handwriting input feature on `Gboard`, your handwritten text is converted into typed text in real-time. As you write, Gboard recognizes ( or may mistake  depending on how good your writing was ) the characters you’re writing and converts them into typed text, which is then entered into the text field of the app you’re using. This means that you can use handwriting input with any app that allows text input, just like you would use the regular keyboard. Gboard does not convert your handwriting into an image.

To do this take a screenshot and it will be stored into the clipboard ( see following  pt below )  and share the screen shot ( provided that app allows image sharing  )

-- Use a `keyboard` app that allows `Image sharing. Gboard` has this feature. To use it turn on the `clipboard` toggle ( have the latest version btw )  - take a `screenshot` ( `Gboard` automatically stores  any  image you put in `clipboard` memory ) and then head to the  app that you want to share it with  ( e.g. Whatsapp or gmail ) . As long as it :

- permits the  text input space ( aka lets a `keyboard` open )
- allows you to "drop" an image.
  You can get this done and that image is in your `clipboard` for a hr or so. After that it gets deleted . To make it permanent `pin` the clipboard and it will be there forever and you can share it as many times as needed.

-- Use the app that generated the  image / scribble. E.g. in `Google Keep`   - you can scribble stuff and use the `system share` dialogue of that app to share it with  other apps like `WhatsApp`. Here is a small  [guide](https://www.androidcentral.com/how-use-clipboard-gboard)

These are the fundamental  approaches to get done what you want

Comment: That is not what question asked for.

Comment: Thanks, I hope these not be useful for someone else.  What I do currently is save the handwriting as an image and share the image. it's quicker than taking a screenshot and cropping the handwriting.

Comment: using `gboard` u cant save handwriting as image unless its screenshot-  when  you use handwriting i/p from gboard it will  convert into text always an  & afaik does does give any save as image option. If you use a specific app that has its own add on to keyboard features then that would perhaps permit it which is what I said -  how to send that handwriting depends on the app interacting with keyboard rather than the keyboard itself - so closest you can come to blanketing a rule is  a screenshot which gboard will save automatically